# How do you get a pirate hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012

I noticed that [one user has a cool pirate hat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673730/luchian-grigore). However, there is no description of what's required to get a hat like that on the winter bash page. Are there "secret" hats, or is this one given out on other SE sites?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you click on the user's avatar on their profile page, you can see their hat collection. If you hover over the pirate hat, a little description offers a hint:

[image: shiver]

Comment: Shiver me timbers! I tried clicking it, but did not try hovering over! Thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight On Stack Exchange, when in doubt, there's likely a tooltip :P

Answer (score 20):

If you know the name of the hat and want a more detailed description, you can go to http://winterba.sh and add the name in the URL, hyphenated and in lowercase.

For the pirate hat you're asking about: http://winterba.sh/shiver-me-timbers

[image]

Of course, this won't work if you don't know the hat's name. :)