# How many people have unlocked a particular hat?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2012

It would be great to find out how many people have unlocked each hat **just like badges**.

Would it be possible for this to be added? Something like "x 153" beside a hat meaning 153 people have unlocked it.

Any feedback on this?

Comment: i at-least know one ... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159515/how-do-you-get-a-pirate-hat but eager  to see all

Comment: @NullPointer It isn't as easy to count if you want to see how many people on SO have it.

Comment: For each site or for the network in general?

Comment: @Dynamic For each site, just like badges.