# Why didn't I get the pirate hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

According to [How do you get a pirate hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159515/how-do-you-get-a-pirate-hat), the highest answer that outscores an accepted answer with a score of 3 or more or by 2x or more wins a pirate hat.

I remember that a few days ago, as it happened, I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979714/heap-sort-how-to-sort/13980081#13980081) and got 6 score,  finally the OP accepted his/her own answer with 0 score.

This is what I thought I have met the requirement of a pirate hat, but why did't I get one?

Comment: Because the accepted answer needs to have a score of 3 at least. It has 0.

Comment: @Oded The brilliant engineers of StackEx forgot to deal with the `devided by 0` case? I don't believe that....

Comment: @Martijn looks like you're right on spot, better post this as an answer. :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I misunderstand the word *with* and *by*. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The pirate hat requires that the accepted answer has a score of 3 or higher:

> provide the highest scoring answer that outscores an accepted answer with a score of 3 or more by 2x or more

In your case the accepted answer only has a score of 0.